# Entity Framework DateTime vs C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a problem where the SQL server datetime format is not matching the C# format.

I need to remove the AM/PM entity framework automatically generating, e.g.

[Extent2].[DateCreated] < '1/7/2018 3:27:27 PM') <--- This should be '2018-01-07 15:35:16.280'

I have the following method:

```
        public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<AlertRequest, bool>> ShouldSendSecondary()
    {
        var diffFive = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5);
        var diffTen = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10);
        var diffTwenty = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20);
        var diffThirty = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30);
        var diffSixty = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-60);
        return e => e.AlertGroup.AlertRules.Select(r => new { r.AlertAfterType, r.DateCreated }).Any(r =>
            (r.AlertAfterType == (int)AlertAfterTypeEnum.FiveMinutes && r.DateCreated < diffFive) ||
            (r.AlertAfterType == (int)AlertAfterTypeEnum.TenMinutes && r.DateCreated < diffTen) ||
            (r.AlertAfterType == (int)AlertAfterTypeEnum.TwentyMinutes && r.DateCreated < diffTwenty) ||
            (r.AlertAfterType == (int)AlertAfterTypeEnum.ThirtyMinutes && r.DateCreated < diffThirty) ||
            (r.AlertAfterType == (int)AlertAfterTypeEnum.OneHour && r.DateCreated < diffSixty));

    }
```

Which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[AlertRequestId] AS [AlertRequestId],
[Extent1].[CreatedByUserId] AS [CreatedByUserId],
[Extent1].[Comment] AS [Comment],
[Extent1].[AlertGroupId] AS [AlertGroupId],
[Extent1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated],
[Extent1].[Status] AS [Status],
[Extent1].[LastSent] AS [LastSent]
FROM [dbo].[AlertRequest] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (3 = [Extent1].[Status]) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[AlertRule] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[AlertGroupId] = [Extent2].[AlertGroupId]) AND (((2 = [Extent2].[AlertAfterType]) AND ([Extent2].[DateCreated] < '1/7/2018 3:27:27 PM')) OR ((3 = [Extent2].[AlertAfterType]) AND ([Extent2].[DateCreated] < @p__linq__1)) OR ((4 = [Extent2].[AlertAfterType]) AND ([Extent2].[DateCreated] < @p__linq__2)) OR ((5 = [Extent2].[AlertAfterType]) AND ([Extent2].[DateCreated] < @p__linq__3)) OR ((6 = [Extent2].[AlertAfterType]) AND ([Extent2].[DateCreated] < @p__linq__4)))
))
```

-- p__linq__0: '1/7/2018 3:27:27 PM' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__1: '1/7/2018 3:22:27 PM' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__2: '1/7/2018 3:12:27 PM' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__3: '1/7/2018 3:02:27 PM' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__4: '1/7/2018 2:32:27 PM' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false)

It's getting thrown off by the mis-matching format. If I simply change to the select p__linq__0 value to '2018-01-07 15:35:16.280' it works.

Comment: Is your column a datetime or a string field? The mismatch shouldn't happen with datetime fields

Comment: I've found one solution: Change the culture info manually. Not very elegant. :         private void SetCulture()
        {
            CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.fff";
            culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        }

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto They are datetimes (in sql and C#). Entity framework is creating a sql query where the variable has an "PM' or 'AM' value, which doesn't work. If I override the default ToString() with new cultureInfo (shown above) it works, but surely that's not the actual fix for comparing dates in Entity Framework?